# Javascript - thing.length not working - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I found a function that counts immediate children of an element. However, whenever I run it, the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')". I am also coding this in VS code, and the error doesn't pop up in the code editor. I have to go to the tab, ctrl+i, and look in the console.
I have no idea what is happening (it should work fine), but here is my code:

```js
function countChildElements(parent) {
  var children = parent.childNodes, cnt = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (children[i].nodeType === 1) {
      cnt++;
    }
  }
  return(cnt);
}

function thing(ev) {
  alert(countChildElements(ev));
}
```

```html
<a onclick="thing(event)">
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>2 children in this element (including this)</p>
</a>
```

Anyone know why this is happening?
PS. I can't use the .length thing anywhere. It always makes that same error thing.

Comment: What is `parent`? It's something that doesn't have a `childNodes` property.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I made it the event of a thingie. Like this: <a onclick = "thing(event)"></a>
And then:
function thing(ev) {
    var hi = countChildElements(ev);
}

Comment: sry I don't know any fancy words you would normally use

Comment: Ev isn’t a thing that has child elements.  Maybe you meant ev.target.

Answer (score 0):

just change the thing

```js
function thing(ev) {
  alert(countChildElements(ev.target.parentNode));
}
```